# How to merge two case statements in one switch statement

Tags: c#, c++

```
switch(code)
{
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
         // to do 
    default:
         // to do 
}
```

Is there any way to merge the two "case" statements together?

Comment: C# and C++ are different languages. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: how about `switch(code.ToUpper())` and just use it in upper case for each `case`.

Comment: You just need `break;` for `case` and `default`

Comment: hi Ant P, either one or both

Comment: @Habib my problem is merge two case to one. the 'break' is not what I concerned.

Comment: Why? The way you have it is idiomatic.

Comment: @user3254788, I am not sure about your question then, you current code can't compile *(at least with C# compiler)*, You can use `char.ToUpperInvariant` which would be better as compare to `char.ToUpper`

Comment: @PaulButcher any better solution?

Comment: @user3254788 converting code to uppercase aka `switch(code.ToUpper())` or using `char.ToUpperInvariant` are not options to you? That was what I was thinking you want, to have `A` and `a` fall into the same `case` by using a single `case`.

Comment: @Habib I did not see all your code at first. your answer is what I want. thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need `break;` for your current code like:

```
switch (code)
{
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        break;
    // to do 
    default:
        // to do 
        break;
}
```

but if you are comparing for upper and lower case characters then you can use [`char.ToUpperInvariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.toupperinvariant%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then specify cases for Upper case characters only:

```
switch (char.ToUpperInvariant(code))
{
    case 'A':
        break;
    // to do 
    default:
        // to do 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int switchExpression = 3;
        switch (switchExpression)
        {
            // A switch section can have more than one case label. 
            case 0:
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 0 or 1");
                // Most switch sections contain a jump statement, such as 
                // a break, goto, or return. The end of the statement list 
                // must be unreachable. 
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                break;
                // The following line causes a warning.
                Console.WriteLine("Unreachable code");
            // 7 - 4 in the following line evaluates to 3. 
            case 7 - 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 3");
                break;
            // If the value of switchExpression is not 0, 1, 2, or 3, the 
            // default case is executed. 
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case (optional)");
                // You cannot "fall through" any switch section, including
                // the last one. 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` will evaluate for every condition met until it hits a `break`, a `default` or the final closing bracket.

i.e it will execute any matching `case` statement until it hits one of those instructions.

Groups all equivilant `cases` and add a `break` after the last to merge them.

Be aware that if there are no matches, it will fall into the `default` block.

Comment: So, if the first statement is `default` followed by `case`s, the cases won't be executed?

Comment: Case and Switch statements are equivalent to GOTO labels, so if any case matches, execution jumps to it; if none match (and default exists) it jumps to default. So no, order doesn't matter

Comment: But you stated "...will evaluate for every condition met until it hits a break, a default,...".  So if default is the first condition, it stops.

Comment: Yes, so Case 'A' = GOTO: a
Case 'a' = either GOTO }, GOTO 'break' or GOTO 'default' depending on which JMP the compiler could generate?